# how to fix error after deploy:mode: developer?

Tags: magento2, cli, less-css

In Magento2, after I created custom.less in myTheme, it does not render file less. so I tried run cli `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

then in the admin panel, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list


};


require...nfig.js (line 381, col 1)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mytheme/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/ui.js"
ui.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mytheme/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js"
jquery-...eapi.js
Error: Script error for: jquery/ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mytheme/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/prototype.js"
prototype.js
Error: Script error for: prototype
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mytheme/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/text.js"
text.js
Error: Script error for: text
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
Error: Load timeout for modules: text!ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html_unnormalized2,text!ui/template/modal/modal-slide.html_unnormalized3,text!ui/template/modal/modal-custom.html_unnormalized4
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
```

I tried removing everything in pub/static except .htaccess and run cli `/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. but there is no change. Any suggestion? Please help me?

thanks

Comment: is it solved ? i am also facing same issue ?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue after deploy. My Magento 2 install was not loading jquery-storageapi.js

I figured out magento2 loads the the core resources from the following folder **lib/web/jquery/** and materializes in **pub/static/....**

I found that this folder was missing the **jquery-storageapi.js**

**So the solution I Applied**

1. Download the jquery storage api https://plugins.jquery.com/storageapi/
2. Copy it to **lib/web/jquery/**
3. Clear the cache

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

I feel that, if you already setup any cache in server it might be the reason. Try to disable the minification (if enables, only works in production mode) and clear the server caches. Do not forget to run **php magento setup:static-content:deploy** after deploy mode set.

I got jquery-storeageapi.js does not load 404 script error and required.js file in pub/static wrong path wrapped with secure folder on staging server.

You can follow below steps and it will be fix.

1) Set deploy mode to production - **php magento deploy:mode:set production**
       (js and css minification will works with production mode.If you are in developer mode with code minified above issues will show up as I experienced it. Also verify using echo the print_r($_SERVER) in index.php that production mode is set before load the website)

2) Clear all the caches setup in server
        **/etc/init.d/nginx restart**
        **/etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm restart**
        **/etc/init.d/varnish restart**

3) Clear the browser cache and view it in incognito mode. That's it!

Cheers!